# Selenium C# cannot click on cookie policy close icon in Mobile Emulation mode

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a test to click the cookie policy close icon on our web page in Mobile Emulation mode but when my test tries to click on the close icon I get the error

"An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code"

It seems to cannot find the element.  I have also tried waiting for the page to load, element to be displayed and a hard coded wait of 5 seconds.  Still no luck.

My XPath which I have tried is:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[contains(@class, 'messageBoxContainer')]//div[contains(@class, 'messageBoxCloseButton icon-cross')]")]
```

Another Xpath I have also tried:

```
//div[@class='messageBoxCloseButton icon - cross']"
```

The HTML snippet is:

```
<div class="messageBoxContainer">
<div class="messageBoxTextInner">
<div class="messageBoxTitle">Cookies on Company a</div>
<div class="messageBoxBody">
    <span class="cookiePolicyText">Company a uses cookies to give you the best experience possible. Please read our</span>&nbsp;
    <span class="cookiePolicyLinkText" data-tap-recogniser="true">Cookie Policy</span> for more details.</div></div>
<div class="messageBoxCloseButtonContainer">
    <div class="messageBoxCloseButton icon-cross" data-tap-recogniser="true"></div></div></div>
```

My Selenium C# snippet is:

```
public void ClickCookieCloseIcon()
        {                
            Actions.Click.Element(Browser, CookieCloseIcon);
        }
```

How do I click the x close icon from this cookie policy please.  Is it my locator causing the problem?
The locators should be the same as Desktop or can Mobile Emulation some locators behave differently?
Thanks for your help.

Riaz

Comment: My XPath is very rusty, but will that find the element you need? What if you simply try finding the inner div and forget about the `messageBoxContainer`?

Comment: Another possible problem might be that your current webdriver PageSource doesn't have that element. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358658/selenium-driver-getpagesource-differs-than-the-source-viewed-from-browser) question.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now.  Our contractor used this Xpath and it is now working

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div[class='cookieWidget'] div[class='messageBoxCloseButton icon-cross']")]
```